# metadata specified (x-amz-mata-metada) S3 file during upload is missing when Syncing file from s3 to On-Premise machine using aws's DataSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded a file to S3 and while uploading a file I have also specified some metadata (x-amz-meta-metdata). Although when I Sync S3 Bucket using aws's DataSync metadata is missing (RightClick file-->Properties-->Details tab in opened popup).
Please let me know how can achieve this task or is it possible to save metadata while saving s3 file to local machine.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by this: "Although when I download that file metadata is missing." Where do you expect this metadata to be saved on your local computer?

Comment: @MarkB in windows file system, when we right click a file the click properties then a popup will appear, In that popup if you click details tab you the find metadata of that file.